# Synergy - Right click on windows with Apple keyboard

Tags: synergy

Using Synergy, I have a Mac set up as the server and a Windows PC set up as the client. When I move my mouse to the Windows machine, I cannot find a way to right click. I have the old white one-button Apple mouse. I tried Control+Click, but no luck. Nothing in the preferences looks helpful. I have searched for a while for a fix, but I haven't found any. I would think this would be a common problem for Synergy. What can I do to get the right click working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think everyone has read this wrong.

If the mac is the server it will not relay a right click because to Mac right click is actually a program locked to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>click and not the other way round. This means if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>Click on windows you will just get <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> click. <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd> will work, but you should be able to also set a hotkey in synergy's hotkeys that will right click. The final thing you can do is switch to using you PC as the server

Assign the button to *mousebutton(3)* and lock it to your Mac screen it will right click (without the stars of course).

The main issue with this is I can't seem to find any hotkey info for text based configuration in the wiki.

Comment: I have tried setting mouse button 3 to be the right click button, which worked, but it's annoying because whenever I click it, I have to be very careful not to scroll at the same time, which happens a lot. I see what you mean about the the Mac always sending a ctrl+click, so I may I have to use the PC as the server if I really miss ctrl+click on Windows. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

It should be just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> click to get a right click. That should pass your OS X right click to Windows. If not, you can select the item you want to right click, and press <kbd>Shift-F10</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found that `shift` + `fn` + `F10` works, but `control` + `click` does not. So I guess I at least have a way now, although not very convenient.

Comment: @woz try "shift" + "control" + left click

Comment: Still nothing. It's the same as a left click.

Comment: @woz I was hoping that would do the trick. Both work for me in VMWare, Parelles, and RDP to Windows. But as I am at work and Synergy is only running at home I was not able to verify.

Answer (score 1):

Much less hassle will be if you can live with enabling "Secondary Click" through the OSX Preferences -> Mouse pane. This will pass the "Right-Click" function to the Windows machine if the OSX machine is indeed the servant.

Just a note!

Comment: This solution works flawlessly with the latest version of Synergy + OS X Mavericks + Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: Just to add this solution works very well, I didn't even realise I had the secondary click set up on my trackpad.